# When the average will change?

Tags: average

I have a random number (eg `455,835`). Starting from `615` downwards I would like to calculate when the two integers average changing.

For example. I know that `603` and `755`'s average is `679`. How can I calculate it with an equation that the next change will happen at `598`?

I can only work with natural numbers. Rational numbers are not allowed.

**Edit:**
Clarification from eyeballfrog:

> So the idea is you have some arbitrary number N choose various x<N.
> You calculate another number y=⌊N/x⌋, then take the truncated average
> ⌊(x+y)/2⌋, and want to know when that average changes.

**Sample**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand how your list is generated. For in the beginning you take the pair $(615, 741)$ then $(614, 742)$ so the first number ticks down and the second ticks up. The two numbers naturally average to the same constant each time because at the $n$:th iteration you are calculating $\frac{(615-n) + (741+n)}{2}=\frac{615+741}{2}$. But, then you skip $761$ which should be at row $22$?

Comment: Hi. In B:4 you can see the equation how the B column is calculated. Integer division. Column A is just -1 each time.

Comment: So the idea is you have some arbitrary number $N$ choose various $x < N$. You calculate another number $y = \lfloor N/ x\rfloor$, then take the truncated average $\lfloor (x + y)/2\rfloor$, and want to know when that average changes. Do I have this correct?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of flooring allow us to simplify the expression to
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{ x + N/x}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
We can also tell that the value will change between $x$ and $x + 1$ if there is a real number $y$, $x < y < x+1$ such that $(y + N/y)/2$ is an integer. Calling this integer $k$, we can set $k = (y + N/y) /2$ and solve for $y$ to get
$$
x = \lfloor y \rfloor = \lfloor k \pm \sqrt{k^2 - N}\rfloor
$$
[Applying this formula to the values $[678, 683]$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFloor%5Bk+-+Sqrt%5Bk%5E2+-+455835%5D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C+678%2C+683%7D%5D) gives $615, 606, 598, 591, 585, 579$, which lines up perfectly with the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you. It works flawlessly.